# Aggregate Initialization - Vectors and Arrays

Tags: c++, c++11

I know the following statements work

```
std::vector<int> a{1,2,4} --->A (Aggregate Initialization)
```

or the following statement(s)

```
std::vector<int> a;
a = {1,2,4};                ---->B  Variable already initialized. - Then aggregate initialization is called
```

However in case of Arrays

```
 int c[3]={1,4};  ---->C (1,4,0)
```

However the following is not allowed

```
int c[3]; 
c = {1,4};   ---->D
```

Now my question is why does B work and D doesnt ?

Comment: Mostly unrelated, but in case you don't know about it, there is a `std::array<T,N>` class: http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/array

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> ```
> std::vector<int> a{1,2,4};
> ```

This is initializer-list initialization, not aggregate, because `vector` is not an aggregate — its data is stored on the heap. You need to have `#include <initializer_list>` for it to work, although that header is typically included from `<vector>`.

> ```
> a = {1,2,4};
> ```

This also goes through a function overloaded on `std::initializer_list`, and the semantics are the same as the function call:

```
a.assign( {1,2,4} );
```

> ```
>  int c[3]={1,4};
> ```

This *is* aggregate initialization. However you cannot do `c = { 3, 5, 6 }` afterward, because the braced-init-lists may only be initializers for new variables, not operands to built-in expressions. (In a declaration, the `=` sign is just a notation for initialization. It is not the usual operator. Braced lists are specifically allowed by the grammar for assignment operators, but this usage is only valid with function overloading, which causes the list to initialize a new variable: the function parameter.)

The answer to your final question is that there's no way to write the necessary `operator =` overload for "naked" arrays, because it must be a member function. The workaround is to use `std::copy` and a `std::initializer_list` object.

Comment: The reason why `c = {1,4}` doesn't work is incorrect, brace-init lists *can* be used in the RHS of assignments (see my answer). The problem here is that arrays are not assignable.

Comment: @juanchopanza Oops, I incompletely corrected that. The problem is that, as the last paragraph says, there is no way to define `operator=` for a C-style array because it must be a member function.

Answer (score 5):

As has been explained in other answers, the mechanism for this assignment is the vector's [`std::initializer_list` assignment operator](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/operator%3D). This makes the following possible with brace enclosed initializer lists of arbitrary value, despite `std::vector<int>` not being an aggregate:

```
std::vector<int> a;
a = {1,2,4};       // OK, vector& operator=(std::initializer_list<T>)
```

> However the following is not allowed

```
int c[3]; 
c = {1,4}; // Error: arrays are not assignable
```

This is because arrays are not assignable. If it were a different kind of aggregate, then this would work. For example,

```
struct Foo { int a, b, c; }; // aggregate
Foo f = {1, 2, 3};           // OK, aggregate initialization
f = { 1, 4 };                // OK
```

Here, `f.a`, `f.b` and `f.c` are assigned the values `1, 4, 0` respectively.

Furthermore, non-aggregates can also be initialized and assigned-to with brace-enclosed initializer lists when they have (non-`explicit`) constructors with a parameter list compatible with the elements of the list. For example,

```
struct Bar
{
  Bar(int a, int b, int c) : a(a), b(b), c(c) {} // non-aggregate 
  int a, b, c;
};

Bar b0 = {1, 2, 3}; // OK
Bar b1 = {1,2};     // Error: number of elements must be 3
b0 = {11, 22, 33}.  // Assignemnt OK
```

Comment: I don't think this syntax is specific to aggregates. You're calling the implicit assignment operator with a temporary generated by aggregate initialization. For non-aggregates, the braced-init-list would be used to select a constructor. Also, +1 because I didn't know about this usage!

Comment: @Potatoswatter I am not saying it wouldn't work for non-aggregates, but that it works for aggregates that are not arrays. I will try to clarify this point.